# How can I fill ng-model query for filtering data using a javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, jqvmap

I use AngularJS for storing data in JSON and want to filter shown on the page items. Each item includes country code as a property:

```
[
 {
  "id": "1",
  "code": "us"
 },
 {
  "id": "2",
  "code": "ca"
 }
]
```

I want to use Jquery VMap to filter items. When I click to the region, the list of items should be filtered. When I use simple "input" field, the list is filtered. But when I use following code that is executed when I click to the county, nothing happens:

```
onRegionClick: function(element, code, region)
 {
  document.getElementById("query").value = code;
  function updateQuery($scope) {
   $scope.query = code;
   $scope.$digest();
  }
 }
```

How can I make Angular knows about the change of "query" or is there any better solution?
Link to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/47RLz/4/

Comment: Use `$("#query").val(code).trigger('input');`

Comment: #1 `updateQuery` function won't run as it's not actually being invoked. #2 You can't access angulars `$scope` from within $.vectorMap.

Comment: How will updateQuery() invoke?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
onRegionClick: function(element, code, region)
 {
    var e = document.getElementById("query");
    var scope = $(e).scope();
    scope.$apply(function() {
        scope.query = code;
    });

 },
```

**Explanation**

In angular, you can retrieve the scope of any element by calling `scope()` on the jQuery element. Once you have the scope, `code` is assigned to the query variable on the scope.

Since the click handler is executing outside of the angular context, the assignment is wrapped in an $apply block to trigger a $digest cycle and update the views.

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/85wfr/1/)

Comment: well done ! would you please give little explanation about what have you done? (for the sake of my knowledge).